# Sudden query problem with higher compatibilty levels on SQL 2022

Tags: sql-server, compatibility-level, sql-server-2022

We recently migrated a db from a SQL2016 server to a SQL2022 server. When we migrated the database we changed the SQL compatibility level to SQL2022 (160). Life was good.

Then suddenly something changed and one stored procedure started giving an error:

> *Msg 8618, Level 16, State 2, Procedure up_MergeToIDMObject, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required is a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size of the fields in the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash (CHECKSUM()) of fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note however that this will change the behavior of the query.*

The stored procedure contains a Merge statement with a complex view with several unions and function use as source and table destination. Both table and view are fine when selected from directly.

When we turn the compatibility level down to SQL2017 (140) everything works fine again. As soon as we put it to SQL2019 or SQL2022 the error resurfaces.

So the questions become:

- Can anyone tell me or point me to documentation that states what changes when you switch to compatibility level SQL 2019 (160)?
- What is in there that is not in SQL2017 that could affect a query so that the above error appears?

I have concluded that it isn't so much a error with the data as much as the plan generator is just tripping over something.

I cannot supply the queries and tables themselves. They are useless without context and could suggest information about a customer. They are not relevant to answering the question as to what is different between compatibility levels.

edit:
I found [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn | SQL) which talks about the differences between the levels and how to turn on and of new features without changing the compat level.

On the change level between 140 and 150 they point to these two, but turning them off made no difference.

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET ROW_MODE_MEMORY_GRANT_FEEDBACK = OFF;
```

and

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET TSQL_SCALAR_UDF_INLINING = OFF;
```

edit2: It was suggested to try the merge with `OPTION (LOOP JOIN, MERGE JOIN)`. That makes it work under the higher compatibility levels at the cost of performance. Adding the hash join back in, breaks it.

Comment: May well be perfectly possible to get the plan requiring an over wide work table on 2017 too. Just a slight difference in cardinality estimates for example means it doesn't end up pursuing that route. Does `ROBUST PLAN` hint solve it?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like `ROBUST PLAN` hint probably won't help as you are already getting this at compile time not run time - can you create a repro and just anonymize table/column names?

Comment: @MartinSmith The hint indeed changed little, but thanks for trying. I also edited the question as to supply several options I tried turning off as the newer level. 
We have used the query without problems for years and its still running well on all other databases that use the same processes. The only difference real difference is in the data in this specific instance. Data that is large and privacy sensitive.
I was hoping to find a specific optimization I could turn off or something like that. Otherwise I'll just have to keep it at level 2017.

Comment: The real nitty gritty of query optimization isn't documented `sys.dm_exec_query_transformation_stats` contains 399 rules in my 2016 instance and 421 in my 2019 instance - maybe one of these additional (undocumented) transformation rules is responsible. Or maybe just some cardinality estimation calculation was tweaked and so you get a different result

Answer (score 0):

> They are not relevant to answering the question as to what is different between compatibility levels.

They are, because the issue isn't likely an explicit feature difference between the compatibility levels, as you assumed. Rather, I wouldn't doubt you're running into one of the [many bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) with the `MERGE` statement, that is just being exposed more with your particular database in a higher version of SQL Server. You [shouldn't use `MERGE`](https://sqlblog.org/merge) in code that matters.

Outside of that, it could just be optimizer differences between SQL Server versions resulting in a different execution plan that requires a `WorkTable` - likely something that induced a sort operation. For example a change in physical join operations, such as going from a `Merge Join` (not to be confused with the `MERGE` keyword), which preserves order, to a `Hash Join` which requires a sort after. You can analyze the plan on the lower compatibility level and compare it to the estimated plan on the higher compatibility level to see if you notice these kind of differences. You can also try running it on the higher compatibility level with `OPTION (LOOP JOIN, MERGE JOIN)` appended to the end of the query to see if that works around the issue. But mostly a guess in the dark right now without seeing the query and table definitions.

That's about the extent of advice anyone can likely provide given the information you've allowed us. If you want to provide the query and it's execution plan, even if [anonymized](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/sql-performance/anonymize-your-plans), then perhaps someone can at least suggest a proper re-write or spot more clues to the root issue.

Comment: " explicit difference between the compatibility levels" strange then that I found a microsoft document that states serveral of the explicit differences for every level.
Merge has served us wel over the years. I'm not going to re-develop it, because one instance of a queries has an issue. Yes it can have issues, but it also has uses that are perfectly fine.

Comment: @zu1b I never said there aren't explicit differences between comparability levels, obviously there are. But the issue you're running into isn't because of any specific one of them. It's either a bug case, or an issue your query always potentially had, but is being exposed now due to performance "*improvements*" with the optimizer that resulted in a different execution plan (as my updated answer states now). Either way, this issue always potentially existed in lower compatibility levels, and there's nothing you can just *turn off* in the higher levels to reasonably fix it.

Comment: "*I'm not going to re-develop it, because one instance of a queries has an issue. Yes it can have issues, but it also has uses that are perfectly fine.*" - Because of the type of issue it is, you'll likely need to re-write the query anyway, if you want to use the higher compatibility level, regardless if you choose to continue to use `MERGE` or not. But at that point I'd listen to the experts (Aaron Bertrand) and not use `MERGE`. Also, please be aware the bugs with `MERGE` can appear unexpectedly with your other queries that have been "*working fine* too" as the data changes

Comment: @zu1b Also, I wouldn't recommend just randomly turning off new features of the higher compatibility level. The ones you listed in your update have nothing to do with the issue you ran into. You risk creating other problems by doing so.

Comment: "That's about the extent of advice anyone can likely provide given the information "
Considering your updated answer, I wasn't expecting much more, but you never know. I thought I made clear I wasn't expecting an in depth answer, The problem is likely in the exact data that is provided to this instance of the database. We have many instances that have run fine for years and still do. Just one is failing a few weeks after the upgrade. Using the lower SQL level is acceptable as the solution is not developed any further, but will have to run for a significant time still.

Comment: "OPTION (LOOP JOIN, MERGE JOIN)" That actually removed the error at higher levels, but makes the query very slow. Adding Hash Join back in to that set, breaks the merge.

Comment: @zu1b Yea, figured so. I'm assuming you're `SELECT`ing a lot of columns or large data type ones, such as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. That would explain the overflow when the query plan tries to sort. I think pretty much your only options are to either 1. continue to stay on a lower compatibility level (and hope the execution plan doesn't change down there, as it's possible for this issue to arise there too), 2. Re-write the query, 3. Use the above query hint and deal with the slowness (but hints can be problematic and are lame to use until absolutely necessary). Good luck!